# How to diff two folders to multiple patch files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, diff

First, I tried asking the same on askubuntu and I'm not getting far there... 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/186114/how-to-diff-two-folders-to-multiple-patch-files/186121#comment231985_186121

So, i'll copy/paste here in hopes SO gives me a working solution...

I'm not much of a unix guy so I'll just go ahead and ask:

I have a following problem - two folders with plenty of subfolders. I need to diff them.

I tried this:

```
diff -drupN vanila_kernel_3.0.8 my_kernel_3.0.8 > kernel.patch
```

and that results in a 185mb file... and not really what I want.

I want the result of the diff to be many smaller patches, ideally one for every changed file with the contents of the change. That means I have t ochange the way I use diff, and I need to put it in some sort of a loop... So i tried running this little script

```
for file in original_308/*.*; do
    diff -dupN "$file" "my_308/${file##*/}" > "$file".patch
done
```

But it doesn't work :/

Ideally, I want to have a .patch file for every change, but having patches for files that changed in original would do just fine (as I could filter the newly added files and just copy them over)

Can someone provide me with a decent way to do this please?

UPDATE:
I know there are 231 altered files between these folders and 4546 newly added files... I'm just interested in generating those 231 patches. I even have a file containing those 231 filenames so that can be used in a script as well.

I used this to generate the changelog

```
diff -qdr -x *.o -x *.cmd -x *.d original_308 my_308 | sed "s/^.* and \(.*\) differ/\1/" | sort > changes.txt
```

and that just prints the filenames that changed, trailed by "only in my_308" files... the 231 files are on the top of that file (the first 231 lines)

So let's make it clear - I want .patch files for source files. If the patches can end up in patches//file_name.c.patch that would be really great...

If you give me PERL scripts please tell me how to best use them since I do not understand that garbage. Please don't fail me SO. I need to get this thing ported, tested and running and I'm wasting time on unix commands and untangible scripts ffs.

Comment: Should I repeat my solution here? :-)

Comment: I won't mind giving you bounty if it works :) in the meantime, i'm trying to pick up bash scripting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their contributions... Here's the end result

```
#!/bin/bash                               
FOLDER_OLD="original"
FOLDER_NEW="changed"
FOLDER_PATCHES="./fresh_patches"

echo "Generating changelog for $FOLDER_OLD --> $FOLDER_NEW"
diff -qdr ${FOLDER_OLD} ${FOLDER_NEW} | sed "s/^.* and \(.*\) differ/\1/" | sort > newchanges.txt

mkdir -p ${FOLDER_PATCHES}                                                                                                           
for newfile in `find $FOLDER_NEW -type f`
do
sufix=${newfile#${FOLDER_NEW}/}
oldfile="${FOLDER_OLD}/${sufix}"

if [ -f $oldfile ]; then
    patchfile="${FOLDER_PATCHES}/`echo $sufix |sed 's/\//_/g'`.patch"
    if [ "`diff $oldfile $newfile`" != "" ]; then
        echo "Make patch ${patchfile}"
        diff -dupN "$oldfile" "$newfile" > "$patchfile"
    fi
else
patchfile="${FOLDER_PATCHES}/ADDONS/${newfile#$FOLDER_NEW}"
    echo "Copy $newfile --> $patchfile"
    mkdir -p "`dirname ${patchfile}`"
    cp $newfile $patchfile
fi
done
```

The script first generates a list of changed files and files unique only to the new project/folder; then it generates a patch file for every file and copies the newly added files to the ADDONS folder (unique to the new project)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
DIR1="vanila_kernel_3.0.8"
DIR2="my_kernel_3.0.8"
OUTDIR="patches"
SUFFIX=".patch"

while IFS="," read f1 f2; do
  filename=${f1#$DIR1}  # remove base dir name
  outfile="${OUTDIR}/${filename}${SUFFIX}"
  mkdir -p $(dirname $outfile)  # make sure output directory exist

  diff -dupN "$f1" "$f2" > "$outfile"
done < <(diff -qdr $DIR1 $DIR2 | awk '/differ$/{print $2","$4}')
```

---

#### Quick explanation:

```
diff -qdr $DIR1 $DIR2 | awk '/differ$/{print $2","$4}'
```

That should give you a list of files that has changed in the form `source_file,dest_file`. Passing that to the `while ...read..` runs the loop body for each changed file, with the filenames stored as `f1` and f2.

```
filename=${f1#$DIR1}  # remove base dir name
```

This strips out the trailing portion of the filename (by removing the base directory) so we can determine the proper path for the output patch file. After that it's just a matter of ensuring that the output directory exists and writing out the diff results on `f1` and `f2`.

The quotes around all the filenames ensure that we can deal with spaces in filenames.

Comment: do i need to add #!/bin/bash at the top to run it? how do i run it?

Comment: You can either pass it directly to bash, i.e. `bash script.sh`, or add `#!/bin/bash` at the top and make it executable, then run it (`./script.sh`). For more info, see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html#sect_02_01_03

Answer (score 2):

you can grab <Learning Perl> book and learn it in a week, Perl is pretty cool, please don't call it garbage.  Here is the shell script for generate patch

```
find ./original_308 -type f | while read file
do
  nfile="./my_308/${file#*original_308/}"
  if [ -f $nfile ]; then
    patchfile="./patch/${file#*original_308/}.patch"
    mkdir -p `dirname $patchfile`
    echo "checking $file $nfile"
    diff -dupN "$file" "$nfile" > "$patchfile" && rm "$patchfile"
  fi
done
```

diff xxx >patch && rm patch  will only remove empty patch files.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on the `kernel.patch` file, even if the options you gave to `diff` are different than those you showed above:

```
perl -ne 'if(m{^diff .* (.*/.*) (.*/.*)}) {
              my $f = $1;
              $f =~ s{/}{_}g;
              open $FH, ">", "$f.patch" or die $!;
          } else {
              print {$FH} $_;
          }' kernel.patch
```

This could break if your filenames contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

1. **List item**

   ```
            $ diff -rauB  old_dir   new_dir   >  patchfile_name

            $ patch --dry-run -p1 -i patchfile_name


            $ patch -p1 -i patchfile_name
   ```

This creates a patch between two directories.

Comment: OP is specifically asking for a multiple-file patch, not a single file. read the question carefully...